# MonoDevelop 2.8 "Show Completion Window" does not work reliably any more. What's wrong?

Tags: osx-lion, intellisense, monodevelop

I am running MonoDevelop 2.8 on Lion.

Today code-completion suddenly stopped working. After a while I found out it simply does not work reliably any more.

When I type a dot, usually the available methods for the object appear, but most of the time that doesn't happen any more. But when I type the object name at the beginning of a line, code completion works again for a minute or so.

I.e.

```
string s = "Hello world."
string t = s.
```

At that point the completion window should appear but doesn't. However, when instead of string t = s.etc. I start a line with "s." the code completion window appears.

```
string s = "Whatever"
s.
```

When I press the keyboard shortcut (ctrl-space) for code completion, I notice that the edit menu turns blue for a second, so apparently the actual command is received by MonoDevelop but doesn't do anything.

I updated MonoDevelop from 2.8.6 (I think) to 2.8.8 but the behaviour did not change. It wasn't like that a few days ago, it only started happening today.

Any ideas?

Update: I just tried running MonoDevelop with a newly-created account on the same computer and code-completion works. Must be something in user-specific config files. I'll see if I can hunt them all down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean out all your pidb files.  They are in your project directories as well as your home directory.

$HOME/Library/Caches/MonoDevelop-2.8/CodeCompletionData/

Comment: I couldn't find that folder on my Mac, same OS though. Any idea where it might have moved to with subsequent Unity changes?